# Is it possible to change the currentPlaybackRate in 0.01 intervals using Swift Programming?

Tags: swift

I have been trying to use a variable that ranges from 0.8 to 1.2 at +/- 0.01  Float intervals to change the currentPlaybackRate of MPMusicPlayerController (by pressing a button).

player2?.currentPlaybackRate = rate

(where rate can equal: 0.80, 0.81, 0.82, ... 1.18, 1.19, 1.20).

I have noticed during playing the music that the rate of music only really changes when the rate value reaches 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2. I assume that this has to do with the the decimal place of the float.

Am I right? Is it possible to be able to change the the rate of the currentPlaybackRate at 0.01 intervals in the code? I really would like to control the music at a 1% interval speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was sent to me from Apple:

Apple Developer Relations 24-Sep-2015 03:00 AM

This issue behaves as intended based on the following:

"If there's audio, you will need to set an audioTimePitchAlgorithm other than AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmLowQualityZeroLatency.  See AVAudioProcessingSettings.h.

MPMusicPlayer does not support setting the rate at such a fine-grained rate.
AVPlayer provides a more configurable playback interface."

Therefore, its is not possible to change the music rate at 0.01 intervals using MPMusicPlayer.